# Does jQuery "change" work on fields loaded from external file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, external, onchange

I have three different forms which I insert through an external .html file. The forms are displayed one at a time. When the user presses "ok" or "back" then the form changes and loads one of the other two forms. So far this works ok.

Now I want to track the user's input and thought of doing it with jQuery "change" triggered for each input field seperately, but it doesn't work. Any help would be great!

```
var tabContent = new XMLHttpRequest();
tabContent.onreadystatechange = processText;
tabContent.open("GET", "tabd.html", true);
tabContent.send();

function processText() {
    if (tabContent.readyState == 4) {
    tab = tabContent.responseText;
    document.getElementById("tabholder").innerHTML += tab;
    focusOnElem();
    }
}
```

The form field:

```
<input id="day" value="15" maxlength="2"/>
```

The event:

```
$("#day").change(function(){
    console.log("change");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

When binding an event the element that triggers that event has to exists in order for it to be bound. When you attach an event handler to a set of elements on page load, only the elements that currently exists in the DOM are affected by that event handler. To also include elements that does not exist in the DOM, but are to be inserted dynamically later on, you will have to delegate the event to an element higher in the DOM that does actually exists, and check if the target element matches the selector. This is called a delegated event handler, and in jQuery would look like this:

```
$('#tabholder').on('change', '#day', function(){
    console.log("change");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time you remove an element from the dom it will lose its associated binding. You need to rebind, put it in a function

Every time you re-insert day into the page call Rebind();

```
function Rebind(){

      $("#day").die().change(function(){
            console.log("change");
      });

}
```

Comment: ...or they could simply use the delegated form of `.on()`, which is tailor-made for such situations.

Comment: FYI: "As of jQuery 1.7, use of .die() (and its complementary method, .live()) is not recommended. Instead, use .off() to remove event handlers bound with .on()" [Source](http://api.jquery.com/die/)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help! I tried your suggestions but they didn't work. I noticed that

```
$('#tabholder').on('change', '#day', function(){
    console.log("change");
});
```

would only work for the textarea not any other inputs. Does it have to do with the fact that I'm changing their value and not innerHTML?

Anyway, the thing that worked for me is using two functions, one to store the current values and is called whenever the iser presses a key:

```
document.onkeydown = function(k) {
        memorise();
}
function memorise() {
        console.log("memorise");
        if (stage == 1) {
            dayMemo = $("#day").attr("value");
            monthMemo = $("#month").attr("value");
            console.log(dayMemo, monthMemo);
        } else if (stage == 2) {
            hourMemo = $("#hour").attr("value");
            minuteMemo = $("#minute").attr("value");
            console.log(hourMemo, minuteMemo);
        } else if (stage == 3) {
            commentMemo = $("#comment").attr("value");
            console.log(commentMemo);
        }
    }
```

and one to regain the values, this one is called whenever I load something from the external files:

```
var tabContent = new XMLHttpRequest();
tabContent.onreadystatechange = processText;
tabContent.open("GET", "tabd.html", true);
tabContent.send();

//this function gets external file and shows previous input values
function processText() {
            if (tabContent.readyState == 4) {
                tab = tabContent.responseText;
                document.getElementById("tabholder").innerHTML += tab;
                focusOnElem();
                showMemo();
            }
        }
function showMemo() {
        $("#day").attr('value', dayMemo);
        $("#month").attr('value', monthMemo);
        $("#hour").attr('value', hourMemo);
        $("#minute").attr('value', minuteMemo);
        $("#comment").attr('value', commentMemo);
    }
```